# Dangers in putting the swiftmailer lib in httpdocs

Tags: php, apache

I am about to install swiftmailer on a webserver, where the hosting company has set very high restrictions on what I can access. I am quite new to serverside scripting and therefore wonder if there is any danger in installing an php extension (library) in httpdocs since it is, to my understanding the most easily accessible part of a web server if you want hack a site? Do I have anything to worry about?

Comment: no danger, but get a new host that restriction is dumb

Comment: It is is honestly the worst company I have ever had to deal with and if it was up to me I would change directly! @Dagon I think you are right, since most other "sensitive" php files are placed there anyway. So if you post an answer I can give you your reward :)

Comment: your the developer say the host is not appropriate.

Comment: Indead, but what are you to do when your "customer" (more like a dude that I know who asked for a favor) has used the same hosting company for 10 years. Its not just that their hosting services suck and they want to sell you shit inside of cPanel, their service is terrible.

Comment: i tell customers where to host, theres a limit with what i can work with, if the hosting is not appropriate i move the site for them. if they refuse, i go find a new customer

Comment: you can always put a .htaccess deny from all in a sub directory i guess. But your job is to tell your client what's best for him.

Comment: Thank you good people of the internet. @Dagon if you could post an answer, so I can close this question it would be sweet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no inherent danger in doing this, but disabling direct access (thanks mpm) via .htaccess is a good idea.